# On the convergence of (eigen)values in perturbation theory ?!

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, symmetric-matrices, perturbation-theory

**Background:** Let $H, H_0$ be real square matrices, we want to estimate the eigenvalues/vectors of
$$H = H_0 + \epsilon R$$
where $0 \leq \epsilon \leq 1$, those of $H_0$ are assumed to be known.

Let $\lambda_0$, $v_0$ be the eigenvalue / eigenvector pair of $H_0$:
$H_0 v_0= \lambda_0v_0$.

For small $\epsilon$, we can assume that the value / eigenvector pair verifies
$Hv = \lambda v$, and that $\lambda \rightarrow \lambda_0$,
$v \rightarrow v_0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.
$$\lambda = \lambda_0 + \epsilon  \lambda_1 + \epsilon^2  \lambda_2+ \epsilon^3  \lambda_3+...  $$
$$v = v_0 + \epsilon  v_1 + \epsilon^2  v_2+ \epsilon^3  v_3+...  $$
where  $ v_1, v_2, v_3,...$, $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3,...$ are the vectors/values that we want to calculate. Submitting the above equalities in $Hv=\lambda v$, we get   the following,
$$(H_0 +\epsilon R)(v_0 + \epsilon  v_1 + \epsilon^2  v_2+ ...) = (\lambda_0 + \epsilon  \lambda_1 + \epsilon^2  \lambda_2+ ...) (v_0 + \epsilon  v_1 + \epsilon^2  v_2+ ...)    $$

The first three orders in $\epsilon$
$$(H_0 - \lambda_0)v_0=0 $$
$$(H_0 - \lambda_0)v_1 = \lambda_1 v_0 -Rv_0 $$
$$ (H_0 - \lambda_0)v_2 = \lambda_2 v_0 + \lambda_1 v_1 -Rv_1$$
$$...$$

Also we have ((..,..) is the  the scalar product)
$$\lambda_1 =  \frac{(w, Rv_0) }{(w, v_0)}$$
$$\lambda_2 =\frac{(w, Rv_1 -  \lambda_1 v_1) }{(w, v_0)}$$
$$...$$
where w stasistfies the following $(H_0^T- \bar{\lambda_0} )w = 0$

**Question:**  If we take $\epsilon =1$, $H$ and $H_0$ are symmetric matrices, and $R$ is a diagonal matrix.

In this case can we say that ?
$$\lambda_i \rightarrow 0,\text{ as }i\rightarrow \infty ?$$

I have noticed that it is always the case of many different symmetric matrices $H$ and $H_0$
(where $R$ diagonal and $\epsilon =1$)  but I do not know how to prove it.

P.S. Maybe the answer is pretty basic, I am not doing research in eigenvalue perturbation theory, but this situation arise in my work.

Any idea will be useful!!

Comment: Do you mean Hermitian symmetric?

Comment: Usually we assume $H_0$ is diagonal and $R$ symmetric. Your assumptions could be transformed to the standard form.

Comment: $\epsilon =1$ doesn't make sense, since $R$ could be replaced by any multiple of $R$.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Yes, symmetric ($H_0, H$ are real matrices). In my case here $H_0$ is not diagonal.

Comment: You could try Chapter 2 (p.63) of [Kato](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf)

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thanks! In fact, the background in the question comes from this chapter, but I did not see a discussion about the convergence of the values in eigenvalue perturbation theory.

Comment: @M.Badaoui did you figure this out?